# How to send authentication request from client application to server application in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to send authentication request from client application to server application in rails?
We are working on rails application where login is required.On opening of that login page & submitting that form parameters it should send that submit request to server application for authentication.Is there any mechanism in rails for this client to server communication?
Please help us to solve this problem.

Comment: The question is a little too vague to give a meaningful answer to. Is there an existing authentication server you are using? What protocol is it using?

Comment: Do you have a preference between HTTP Basic Auth or HTTP Digest Auth or `POST` to a `<form>`?

Comment: Rails is a web application framework...is it all about client/server interaction.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple model based ruby authentication solution called: [authlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic)

and here is a [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic)